# RMI compatibility with ServerSocket in a java server program

Tags: sockets, rmi, serversocket

Good day stackoverflow. Presently I have a java server program which communicates with the client application through sockets(using the java ServerSocket and Socket classes). But I intend to develop another client application with an interface for configuring the server application, for which I would like to use RMI(Remote Method Invocation).

The question now is: is it possible and safe to use RMI in a java server program in which ServerSockets and Sockets are also being used? I am familiar with sockets good enough but new to RMI. I have gone through RMI documentation and other sources but got no answers yet. Please I would be obliged if someone can help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no problem. Just make sure you are not using the same sockets.

Comment: ... which is almost impossible anyway.